# como convertir un pdf a jpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Necesito hacer un programa que tomo un archivo pdf que tiene unos datos y dos gráficas y lo convierta a jpg para insertarlo dentro de otro pdf con una información adicional o poder adicionarle al pdf primero una segunda página con la información adicional.

He estado investigando y encontré que podía hacerlo con PyPDF2, pero no lo he logrado. No logré identar bien el código ni adicionar el archivo pdf.

Este es mi código:

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open('C:\1.pdf')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print (page_content)
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python34\pruebasya\manejo-pdf2.py", line 3, in <module>
>     pdf_file = open('c:\1.pdf')
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\x01.pdf'
> ```

Comment: Usa la barra inclinada hacia la derecha (forward slash) en las rutas: `open('c:/1.pdf')` como se hace en los sistemas *nix.

Comment: cordial saludo, hice el cambio que me propuso y me generó el siguiente error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\pruebasya\manejo-pdf2.py", line 2, in <module>
    pdf_file = open('C:/1.pdf')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/1.pdf' el archivo si existe

Comment: Freddy también se puede usar  strings crudos: `open(r'c:\1.pdf')` o escapar la barra inclinada:  `open('c:\\1.pdf')`. De todas formas esto no debe influir, asegúrate de que el nombre y ruta son correctos. Esto intenta abrir un archivo **llamado  `1.pdf`** que se localiza en la **raíz de tu unidad C:**. Es importante que te asegures de no haber agregado una extensión manualmente y tener las extensiones ocultas en la configuración del explorador (tu archivo podría llamarse en realidad  `1.pdf.pdf`. Mira las propiedades (Click derecho -> Propiedades) del archivo y comprueba nombre y ruta.

Comment: Si señor tiene razón efectivamente al mirarlo por detalles estaba como 1.pdf.pdf, corregí esa parte pero me saco otro error :  PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:1079]
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__ self.read(stream) File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read    stream.seek(-1, 2) io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks  la parte donde le doy la ruta asi: pdf_file = open ('C:\\1.pdf') gracias

Comment: Prueba abriendo el archivo  en modo binario: `pdf_file = open ('C:\\1.pdf', 'rb')`

Comment: gracias por responder hice lo que me dijo y saca este este mensaje PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'1' b'0' [pdf.py:1666]
PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'2' b'0' [pdf.py:1666]
PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'3' b'0' [pdf.py:1666]
PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'20' b'0' [pdf.py:1666] y muestra todo en blanco

Comment: Cuando debe uno pasar una pregunta al chat?..pues no es un debate pues yo la verdad no soy experto, estoy aprendiendo y a veces no se si pregunte  bien o con lo que me dicen debo seguir buscando.  Gracias

Comment: Freddy lo que obtienes son avisos solamente. Los pdf están pensados para ser muy buenos para su lectura e impresión por el usuario pero son bastante problemáticos a la hora de obtener datos de los mismos ya que son muy variables (la norma ISO solo proporciona algunas reglas). El funcionamiento de extractText  varía mucho entre pdfs, en algunos funcionará muy bien y en otros no.No he trabajado mucho con pdf en Python y casi siempre es para generar un reporte, si fuera posible que subieras el pdf via GoggleDrive o cualquier otra forma a lo mejor podemos ayudar en algo reproduciendo el problema.

Comment: En cuanto a tu segunda duda, tu pregunta es correcta, lo único es que los errores que tienes ahora no son reproducibles al depender del pdf en custión. Los comentarios se deben usar solo para aclarar una publicación y no deben pasar a ser conversaciones largas, en estos casos se crea una sala de chat asociada a la pregunta para poder hablar más libremente con el mismo fin: aclarar la pregunta. No se trata de pasar la pregunta al chat, lo que si aconseja a veces es plantear preguntas amplias, basadas en opiniones o pidiendo recomendaciones en el chat ya que no son preguntas válidas en el sitio.

Comment: Gracias por responder, buenos días, yo la verdad necesito es convertirlo a jpg, texto e imagen como jpg, voy a tratar de añadir el archivo, no pesa nada la verdad es solo una página con u nos datos de paciente y dos graficas, la idea es dejarlo como jpg, para insertarlo todo tal cual en otro pdf con unos datos adicionales.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/88o895qfvbn5yhd/AAB-UuRUkYqfcPtEiTONo8dTa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea posible hacer esto con ***PyPDF2*** (convertir pdf a jpg), como ya he comentado no he usado esta biblioteca pero viendo la documentación parece no tener esta capacidad. Si que puedes coger la página completa y agregarla como tal a otro pdf. También sería posible obtener imágenes (que son guardadas como tal en el documento) de un pdf con ella, pero tu realmente no tienes imágenes como tales en tu pdf.

Para convertir un pdf a imágenes puedes hacer uso de [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Se trata de una suite de software multiplataforma que permite mostrar, editar, crear y convertir una gran cantidad de formatos de imágenes.

Existen multitud de bindings para Python, uno de los más recientes y el único con el que he trabajado es [Wand](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wand).

Tienes que [instalar Imagemagick según tu sistema](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), la gran mayoría de distros Linux tienen además su propio paquete en los repositorios oficiales si no quieres compilar desde fuentes. Después solo debes instalar Wand (via pip).

Hecho lo anterior puedes usar algo como esto:

```
import os
from wand.image import Image, Color


def pdf_to_jpg(pdf_path,  output_path = None, resolution = 200):
    pdf_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]
    if not output_path:
        output_path = os.path.dirname(pdf_path)

    with Image(filename=pdf_path, resolution=resolution) as  pdf:
        for n, page in enumerate(pdf.sequence):
            with Image(page) as image:
                image.format = 'jpg'
                image.background_color = Color('white')
                image.alpha_channel = 'remove'
                image_name = os.path.join(output_path, '{}-{}.jpg'.format(pdf_name, n))
                image.save(filename = image_name)

pdf_to_jpg("1.pdf")
```

Lo he probado con tu pdf y  se obtiene la imágen perfectamente.

Si quisieras obtener partes de la hoja por separado (por ejemplo obtener las gráficas), si todos tus pdfs tiene exactamente la misma disposición puedes simplemente recortar las partes que quieras de la imagen resultante.

---

Dependiendo del sistema es posible que se tenga que instalar [GhostScrip](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), al ser una dependencia de ImageMagick, si no está instalado en el sistema. Es importante instalar la versión adecuada a la versión de Python y ImageMagick que estemos usando (32 o 64 bits).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, hasta ahora pude seguir mirando, en estos momentos estoy instalando Wand y tratando de configurarlo en windows, estoy teniendo problemas con eso.Voy a seguir intentándolo muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @FREDDYLLANOS puedes descargar ImageMagick  de http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/. Wand se instala via pip. Aquí tienes una pequeña guía de como instalar en windows y como configurar el PATH: http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows. Si tienes cualquier problema comenta a ver si te puedo ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: Primero que todo muchas gracias por la colaboración, seguí las instrucciones y me saca este error en la parte final File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.BlobError: unable to open image `1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701 Yo tengo un equipo con windows 10 pro , este es mi path C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q8;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q8;;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\..Yo realmente necesito convertir todo el pdf a jpg. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @FREDDYLLANOS a la función le tienes que pasar la ruta válida del archivo pdf, en este caso deberías tener el archivo llamado 1.pdf en el mismo directorio del script. Debes llamar a la función por ejemplo como `pdf_to_jpg("C:/Users/Freddy/documentos/archivo.pdf")`. Igualmente puedes pasar dos argumentos opcionales, un segundo argumento con la ruta donde se guarde la imágen y un tercero para la resolución. En las rutas gasta cuidado de no tener configurado el explorador para que oculte la extensión y que tu archivo se llame `1.pdf.pdf` por ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas tardes, nuevamente gracias por responder a mi duda, he probado varias formas de asignar la ruta de mi archivo pero en todas me saca el error: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception   raise e wand.exceptions.DelegateError: PDFDelegateFailed `El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/809 las pruebas que hice fueron : 1."C:\1.PDF", 2."C:\\1.PDF", 3."C:/1.PDF", 4."C://1.PDF" Asigne el nombre a una variable y luego la pase como parametro en la funcion, porque directamente me sacaba error en la " final.

Comment: @FREDDYLLANOS he podido testear el código en Windows 10 y he conseguido que funcione sin problemas. El problema era que necesitas instalar GhostScript: https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html. Usa la versión  adecuada a tu versión de Python (32 o 64 bits). En Windows 10, con Python 3.6.3 - 64 bits, Wand, ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16 y GhostScript 9.22 64 bits (licencia AGPL) funciona perfectamente con tu pdf. Ha sido un error tonto por mi parte, ya que GhostScript es una dependencia de ImageMagick, y no estar acostumbrado a usar estas herramientas en entornos Windows...

Comment: Ya instalé pero me sigue saliendo un error, este es mi fuente

Comment: Corrijo lo anterior, quedo perfecto, muchas pero muchas gracias, sin su ayuda creo que me hubiera demorado mucho en solucionarlo.

Comment: Que debo hacer para indicar que esta fue la respuesta indicada?

Comment: Hola @FREDDYLLANOS, me alegro que al fin te funcione. Para aceptar una respuesta debes hacer click en el "check" que hay a la izquierda de la respuesta, debajo de la puntuación. Puedes mirarte este enlace para ver como funciona: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089). Un saludo.