# Extraer texto de jpg con python

Tags: python

quiero convertir un PDF a JPG, para después extraer el texto, pero ya me atore en la conversión a jpg. alguna sugerencia que me puedan hacer?

```
import wand

**#convertir pdf a imagen**

from wand.image import Image



with Image(filename=path_absoluta, resolution=400) as img:

img.resize(1850,1850)

img.save(filename="prueba2.jpg")
```

Comment: Solo para estar seguro, ¿el PDF no contiene ya texto, verdad? Es decir, lo que quieres extraer no se puede leer como texto del PDF porque hace parte de una imagen. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112682/187094) ya explica cómo convertir de PDF a JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
    
# importar módulos
    
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import sys
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os
    
# Pasar .pdf a imagen .jpg y sacar texto a fichero .txt
    
PDF_file = 'probaext002.pdf'
    
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file,500)
    
contador = 1
    
for page in pages:
    filename = 'page_'+str(contador)+".jpg"
    page.save(filename,'JPEG')
    contador = contador + 1
        
filelimit = contador - 1
outfile = 'otrotexto02.txt'
    
f = open(outfile,'a')
    
for i in range(1, filelimit+1):
    filename = 'page_'+str(i)+'.jpg'
    text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename)))))
    text = text.replace('-\n','')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
    
print(' trabajo hecho... fichero listo ')
```

Cargas el fichero `pdf` y con `pdf2image` lo conviertes a `.jpg`, a continuación con `pytesseract` extraes el texto a un fichero .`txt` (en mi caso necesitaba el texto también)